# How was authentication built on LDAP?

Tags: authentication, ldap

I many times integrate authentication in application based on LDAP.

I just put configs: *URL* (like `ldap.company.com:389`), *search base* (like `dc=europe,dc=com`) and *query pattern* (like `(uid=$)`) to  libraries and frameworks.

But I always wonder what really do libraries and frameworks to actually authenticate user by supplied login/password.

Seems that LDAP has three type of authentication itself - anonymous, plain password and SASL. So sometimes in order to authenticate you need application login/password to get access to LDAP service.

I am not sure that this blog answer the question: http://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/ldap-authentication-authorization-dissected-and-digested/ :

- Get a connection to the LDAP server.
- Bind as the application user.
- Search for the DN (distinguished name) of the user to be authenticated.
- Bind as user to be authenticated using DN from step 3.

Is that right?

That may be summarized as (as experiment in command line):

```
$ ldapsearch -x -h ldap.company.com -s sub -b 'dc=europe,dc=com' "uid=XYZ"
....
dn: uid=XYZ,dc=sales,dc=europe,dc=com
...
$ ldapsearch -W -h ldap.company.com -D 'uid=XYZ,dc=sales,dc=europe,dc=com' \
    -s sub -b 'dc=europe,dc=com' "uid=XYZ"
```

Are there any other authentication schema like using specific DN attribute value as user secret? Or `userPassword` is that attribute itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your four steps are basically correct. SASL is an External Authentication Mechanism where Authentication is "handed" off to the SASL Mechanism. [RFC 4513](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4513) spells out Authentication and Security Mechanisms.

-jim